# vue 3. how to build NPM library. ref() dont work in npm package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

hello i made a simple library for vue 3
my code.

```
export class REfTest() {
  private ref = ref(null)
  constructor(value: any) { this.ref.value = value }

  update(value) {
    this.ref.value = value;
  }

}
```

i used npm link
Created an instance of a class from a library.
But nothing works.
For some reason, reactivity stopped working.
Also, the file with all the library code weighs 160 kilobytes.
It's a lot.
As I understand it, he compiled and added vue3 to this file, which is why it does not work and the file is so large.
here is the dependency file

```
{
  "name": "ref-tets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

I pointed out that vue3 is a peer dependency.
but didn't help

Comment: solution for me

add to webpack following field
`externals: {
  vue: 'vue'
},`

Comment: If it's public lib, it's incorrect to use `externals`. This is what users need to do in case they don't want to bundle Vue

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to import ref from vue.

Please add below line to top of the code snippet.

```
import { ref } from "vue"
```